# signe textview and show last 2digits with different colour in android

Tags: android

I have used one textview and value set for it is like ex:11,234.45 and after decimal values like 45 should be shown with reduced front like 12sp and different colour like grey and 11,234 with black colour with front 16sp. how to achieve this using single textview in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that if you follow this steps

First you need to split you string into 2 strings with this code lines

```
  String s ="11,234.45";
  String[] split = s.split(".");
  String firstSubString = split[0];
  String secondSubString = split[1];
```

Then you change the font size and color of secondSubString  like this

```
  SpannableString ss=  new SpannableString(secondSubString);
  ss.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 5, 0); // set size
  ss.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 5, 0);// set color
```

You can change firstSubString  size and color like this

```
  SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(firstSubString);
  ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 5, 0); // set size
  ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, 5, 0);// set color
```

Finally you set your string to the TextView

```
  TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
  tv.setText(ss1 + "." + ss);
```

Comment: what about colour and size of firstSubString?

Comment: You can the same at secondSubString, that a look at updated answer. Accept the answer if it helps you :)